# Best way to store this data in data store google app engine

Tags: html, database, json, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am trying to make a phone app for my university's notice board.

This is the [notice board](http://intranet.iiit-bh.ac.in/). And each notice is served as an [HTML page](http://hib.ximb.ac.in/Hibiscus/Pub/nbDocDet.php?docid=3685&client=iiit). The URL structure of the notices are simple, with "docid" giving each notice's ID. As far as I guessed from the pattern its an auto incrementing key.

My strategy so far has been to get the HTML file from with a get request, by incrementing the docid value. Parse the html to get the desired values, e.g Title, Posted by, Attention, Date and body.

Initially to store the existing notices to the datastore, then a cron job can check for new notices.

These sets of values will be served as JSON to the phone app.

The body part of the notice is formatted using HTML tags. I would like to retain the formatting. I am simply storing the body as a string which contains all the html tags. Could this be a problem somehow? Is there a better way to preserve the formatting?

I have to do this because i have no way of knowing upfront what sort
    of formatting is done

Comment: The content of the notices is most likely coming from a database -- is there an existing API or direct connection to the database that you could use to get JSON right away? If not, why not just display the individual notices in a web view in your mobile app? Much less work and much more stable than parsing HTML.

Comment: No existing API.

Webview is what I have in mind, but only for the body data. At a later stage I also want to send notifications for new notices, thus I am storing values. So when a new value is added to the db, a notification method is triggered.

I guess instead of storing all the values for the notice I can just store DocID. And serve the notice content directly by getting it from the original HTML file